# Adding links to another page in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

```
<a class="info" href="app/views/pages/new_idea.html">Click!!!</a>
```

This is my code to link to another page from my `index` page on clicking an option. It worked separately. but after integrating it into rails, its not working. this is the error msg.

> No route matches [GET] "/app/views/pages/new_idea.html"

**EDIT:**

These are the routes:

```
$ rake routes | grep pages

     root GET    /                         pages#index_student 
    pages GET    /pages(.:format)          pages#index 
          POST   /pages(.:format)          pages#create 
 new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      pages#new 
edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit 
     page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show 
          PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update 
          PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update 
          DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#destroy
```

Comment: sorry, my code is

Comment: <h2>Post an Idea</h2>
                <a class="info" href="app/views/pages/new_idea.html">Click!!!</a>

Comment: please add your link code here

Comment: run this commad in your terminal rake routes | grep pages and add its result here

Comment: Try this, <a href="/new_idea">Click!!!</a>

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/new_idea.html"

Comment: after running the command, i got  rake routes | grep pages
     root GET    /                         pages#index_student
    pages GET    /pages(.:format)          pages#index
          POST   /pages(.:format)          pages#create
 new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      pages#new
edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
     page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
          PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
          PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
          DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#destroy

Comment: Should I do something in routes.rb file?

Comment: no just try this,  <a href="<%= new_page_path%>">Click!!!</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined route for your `new_idea` action

Add the following in **routes.rb**

```
resources :pages do 
  collection do
    get :new_idea
  end
end
```

Adding this will give you:

```
new_idea_pages GET    /pages/new_idea(.:format) pages#new_idea
```

Then you can use:

```
<a href="<%= new_idea_pages_path %>">Click!!!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<a href="<%= new_page_path %>">Click!!!</a>
```